# Layered Navigation not affecting result on page

Tags: magento, navigation

I have created a module to show all products with special price.

I have added layered navigation to left block. It shows proper product count. But When I click any of filter (like category, price range), it doesn't affect number of products on page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This question better belongs on magento.stackexchange.com, as it does not contain any code and asks a question specific to the behavior of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of above problem.

Previously I was using my own custom layer where I was creating **collection of products with special price**.

Now I changed the code, I am using default **catalog layer** and in my block file (i.e. list.php) I added code to fetch products with special price.

I didn't added any code to filter result. Magento do it by itself.